# using xlsx package in R to adjust page setting in xlsx file

Tags: r, xlsx

I am trying to change the page setting of a xlsx file so that it will be printed as landscape, but not portrait, I tried the following:

```
library(xlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet <- createSheet(wb, "Sheet1")
ps <- printSetup(sheet, landscape=TRUE, copies=3)
```

This is OK if I create a new Excel workbook, but I can't use it when I am using the `loadWorkbook` function to load an xls file. I wonder why.

**Update**: I am working on a xls file but not xlsx file and found the answer below cannot solve my problem, any further suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can get it to work by using `getSheets` to select the sheet to set the print area for:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx")
printSetup(getSheets(wb)[[1]], landscape=TRUE, copies=3)
saveWorkbook(wb,"test.xlsx")
```